# better ways to load views using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

OK. Let me try to explain my problem. I have three pages `index, profile, contact` and three links or navigation buttons in the header. When user clicks on `profile` button `profile.html` is loaded dynamically from the server using `jquery load()` method and place it in the `div` called `container`. Same goes for all pages. Now I also load all of my jquery plugins including jquery shadow plugin, script.js and jquery library on the index page only once. Now what I have is that on `profile` page I have a div tag on which I want to apply a jquery shadow plugin in my script.js which is loaded in index page. But it does not work this way(no idea why). What I have to do to make it work is to add a `script` tag in profile page and inside this I apply this shadow plugin to div tag which is inside profile page.

So this is what I want to ask is, Is there a better way to load pages through ajax using jquery so that whatever javascript code I am applying to all of the pages should be applied to all pages?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you load the script in index and the profile page is loaded within index, then the scripts should work.

Comment: I agree with you that it should work but it does not work.

Comment: Its hard to say without seeing the code.

Comment: Ok my question is that is there a better way t load pages dynamically through ajax using other function except `load()`

Comment: how are you applying the shadow plugin in the `index` page?